# How to change variable name using for loop

Tags: vb.net

I need some help on how to change the variable name using for loop.

Dim "DGV2Max" & j, I want it like this.

this is to minimize my line of codes.

> ```
>    For j As Integer = 1 To 29 Step 1
>        Dim DGV2Max1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
>        DGV2Max1.DataPropertyName = "Max1"
>        DGV2Max1.HeaderText = "Max1"
>        DGV2Max1.Name = "Max1"
>        DataGridView2.Columns.Add(DGV2Max1)
>    Next
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just using the variable to add it to `DataGridView2`, then don't worry about changing the variable name. Use your loop variable & append it to your properties:

```
For j As Integer = 1 To 29 Step 1
   Dim DGV2MaxCol As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
   DGV2MaxCol.DataPropertyName = "Max" & j
   DGV2MaxCol.HeaderText = "Max" & j
   DGV2MaxCol.Name = "Max" & j
   DataGridView2.Columns.Add(DGV2MaxCol)
Next
```

The scope of that variable is only for the current iteration of the loop, so you can reuse it on each iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought there will be a conflict if didn't change the variable name for new textboxcolumn.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to add values to the array elements.

I got your question, Now all you need is just to use an array like this:

```
Private Sub BtnAddNewColumns_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAddNewColumns.Click

    Dim MyArr(29) As String

    For i As Integer = 1 To 29 Step 1
        MyArr(i) = "DGVCol" & i
    Next

    For i As Integer = 1 To 29 Step 1
        Dim DGV2Max1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        DGV2Max1.DataPropertyName = MyArr(i)
        DGV2Max1.HeaderText = MyArr(i)
        DGV2Max1.Name = MyArr(i)
        DataGridView2.Columns.Add(DGV2Max1)
    Next

End Sub
```

I hope this works well for you bro, 
^_^